# PostgreSql. Разница между последней и первой записей

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSql 9.1.
Имеется таблица

```sql
CREATE TABLE weight_archive
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  dtime timestamp DEFAULT now(),
  cycle_num integer,
  massa integer
)
```

cycle_num - номер цикла, каждая новая запиись прибавляет 1

massa - постоянно увеличивающееся число

Необходимо из выборки

```sql
SELECT dtime, cycle_num, massa FROM weight_archive WHERE dtime > '2015-10-01' AND dtime < '2015-10-02'
```

получить разницу (cycle_num и massa) между последней и первой записей.
Например выборка дала:

```
2015-10-01 08:00  |  10  |   50
2015-10-01 09:00  |  11  |   60
2015-10-01 10:00  |  12  |   80
2015-10-01 12:00  |  13  |   100
2015-10-01 14:00  |  14  |   120
```

Нужно получить 14-10=4, 120-50=70. Все одним запросом

UPD. Вечером вчера немного запарился, самое главное забыл.

Нужно выборку нужно делать из всей таблицы за каждые 12 часов, т.е. в результате должно получиться несколько строк в каждой сумма массы и циклов за каждыу 12 часов.

Например таблица:

```
2015-10-01 08:00  |  1  |   0
2015-10-01 09:00  |  2  |   10
2015-10-01 10:00  |  3  |   30
2015-10-01 12:00  |  4  |   40
```

---

```
2015-10-01 22:00  |  5  |   50
2015-10-01 23:00  |  6  |   60
2015-10-02 01:00  |  7  |   70
2015-10-02 02:00  |  8  |   75
2015-10-02 04:00  |  9  |   80
```

---

```
2015-10-02 10:00  |  10  |   85
2015-10-02 12:00  |  11  |   100
2015-10-02 14:00  |  12  |   120
```

---

Получаем:

```
2015-10-01 20:00 | 4 | 40
2015-10-02 08:00 | 5 | 30
2015-10-02 20:00 | 3 | 35
```

Answer (score 1):

Для Вашей задачи сначала можно получить список доступных интервалов, потом соединить их с исходной таблицей и сгруппировать, чтобы получить нужный результат:

```
with recursive intervals(begin_date, end_date, max_date, interval_num) as
(
  -- Получаем начальный интервал
  select 
    q.begin_date, 
    q.begin_date + interval'12 hour' end_date, 
    q.end_date max_date,
    1 interval_num
  from 
  ( -- Берем минимально возможную и максимально возможную даты для интервалов
    select 
      date_trunc('day', min(dtime)) - interval'1 day' + interval'20 hour' begin_date, 
      date_trunc('day', max(dtime)) + interval'1 day 8 hour' end_date
    from weight_archive
  ) q
  where q.end_date > q.begin_date
  union all
  -- Рекурсивно получаем остальные интервалы, прибавляя к предыдущему интервалу по 12 часов 
  -- до тех пор, пока не достигнем максимальной даты.
  select 
    i.end_date begin_date, 
    i.end_date + interval'12 hour' end_date, 
    i.max_date,
    i.interval_num + 1
  from intervals i
  where i.end_date + interval'12 hour' <= i.max_date
)
select 
  max(i.end_date) dt,
  max(cycle_num) - min(cycle_num) + 1 cycle_diff, 
  max(massa) - min(massa) massa_diff
from intervals i
 join weight_archive wa on wa.dtime >= i.begin_date and wa.dtime < i.end_date
 group by i.interval_num
 order by max(i.begin_date)
```

Полный пример на [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5614c/17).

---

Изначально я не совсем внимательно изучил пример данных и решил, что интервалы не заданы строго, а должны высчитываться исходя из данных. Т.е. сначала берем данные за первые 12 часов от первой записи, потом за следующие 12 часов от последующей записи и т.п. Чтобы добро не пропадало приложу и этот пример на [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5614c/1).

Answer (score 0):

Если масса и цикл постоянно увеличиваются, тогда можно просто взять разницу между минимумом и максимумом, т.е.

```sql
SELECT MAX(cycle_num) - MIN(cycle_num) as cycle_diff, MAX(massa) - MIN(massa) as massa_diff
FROM weight_archive 
WHERE dtime >= '2015-10-01' AND dtime < '2015-10-02'
```

Comment: Спасибо. Так все просто, оказывается.

Comment: это верно только в случае линейного изменения параметров, если же massa будет меняться так [10, 1, 20, 2, 30] то результат не будет ответом на поставленный вопрос

Comment: @norbornen верно, но в постановке сказано: cycle_num - номер цикла, каждая новая запиись прибавляет 1; massa - постоянно увеличивающееся число. Если бы таких условий не было, очевидно, я бы не предложил настолько простой вариант реализации.

Answer (score 0):

В данном запросе для определения последний и первой записи используется ID если это не так то ID необходимо заменить на  dtime

```
 where dtime =  (select min(dtime ) as mid from weight_archive
```

Сам запрос

```
select *,m.cycle_num-a.cycle_num as diff_cycle_num , m.massa-a.massa as diffmassa
from (select cycle_num,massa  from weight_archive where id = 
                       (select min(id) as mid from weight_archive where dtime >= '2015-10-01' AND dtime < '2015-10-02') ) a
left join (select cycle_num,massa from weight_archive where id = 
                       (select max(id) as mid from weight_archive where dtime >= '2015-10-01' AND dtime < '2015-10-02')
           ) m on 1=1
```

[Пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a06c1/3)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я еще UPD написал. Нужно получить несколько строк за каждые 12 часов. Определнение первой и последней записи min(cycle), min(massa), min(dtime). Любое корректно.